# counting arithmetic progressions $a, a+r, a+2r$ in a list

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, lists

I have a large list $L$ of numbers and I need to count instances of elements $a,b,c \in L$ such that $a +c = 2b$. A brute-force approach would be to check all possible triples $(a,b,c)$ and this will run in $L^3$ time.

Can I do any better?

Comment: What kind of numbers? It is probably easy if you consider $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but possibly harder with complex numbers in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @babou integers or integers mod p.

Comment: Let $max(L) = m$, I believe you can use FFT for a runtime of $\mathcal{O}(m \log{m} + n)$. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560523/onlogn-algorithm-find-three-evenly-spaced-ones-within-binary-string

Comment: How many triples, which satisfy the condition $a + c = 2b$, are in the list $(0, 0)$? It seems to me, 8

Comment: @MichaelXu I notice it uses a bitmask rather than the list of number itself, which is fine.  The [FFT](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/boolean-analysis/lecture27.pdf) approach shoudl be related to Roth's theorem in mathematics, counting arithmetic progressions like these.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the OP is rather unprecise as to the kind of numbers he is
considering (though he later said integers or integers modulo $p$ in a comment), I will try to answer nevertheless, by trying to limit the
number of assumptions I can make. And while I am at it anyway, I will
generalize a bit.

*This builds on the contributions of previous answer and comments, by 
[Rick Decker](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28932#28933), [Hendrik Jan](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/counting-arithmetic-progressions-a-ar-a2r-in-a-list/28933#comment58119_28933). and [HEKTO](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/counting-arithmetic-progressions-a-ar-a2r-in-a-list/28933#comment58122_28933).*

**Generalized statement of the problem**

We consider four sets of values $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}, \mathcal{W}, \mathcal{Z}$, two functions $f:\mathcal{U}\times
\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{Z}$ and $g:\mathcal{W}\to\mathcal{Z}$. Given 3
sets or
lists of values $U,V,W$, respectively from $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V},
\mathcal{W}$,  count the number of triples $(u,v,w)\in U\times V\times W$ such
that $f(u,v)=g(w)$. Each computation of the functions $f$ and $g$ is supposed to
be in constant time.

Let $n=max(|U|,|V|,|W|)$

**General solution**

*This is essentially [HEKTO's suggestion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/counting-arithmetic-progressions-a-ar-a2r-in-a-list/28933#comment58122_28933).*

Build a hash table containing each value $w\in W$ indexed by
$g(w)$. This has a cost $O(n)$ under the [Simple Uniform Hashing Assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_%28computer_science%29)(SUHA). Without the SUHA, one can use a balanced tree with complexity $O(n\log n)$.

Then for each $u\in U$ and for each $v\in V$ check whether
$f(u,v)$ is in the hash table in constant time (or in the balanced tree in logarithmic time). If it is in an entry $g(w)$, then add $(u,v,w)$ to the
list of solutions (or increase the solution count by one).

Complexity is $O(n^2)$ with hash table, under SUHA, or $O(n^2\log n)$ with a balanced tree.

**Case of ordered sets**

*This is essentially [Hendrik Jan's suggestion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/counting-arithmetic-progressions-a-ar-a2r-in-a-list/28933#comment58119_28933).*

We assume that one of the two sets $\mathcal{U}$ or $\mathcal{V}$ (say $\mathcal{V}$, w.l.o.g.) and the
set $\mathcal{Z}$ are totally ordered and that the function $f$ is monotonic with respect to
the argument in the ordered set (here the second argument).

Then we can have a modified algorithm that does not need a hash table.

First sort the set $V$.

Build a list $L$ of pairs $(w,g(w))$ for all $w\in W$, sorted with respect
to the second element.

Then for each $u\in U$, compare the ordered values of $f(u,v)$ with
the ordered values $g(w)$ of the pairs in $L$, by moving up the two
list $V$ and $L$ as you would do for set intersection, and add the answer
$(u,v,w)$ whenever $f(u,v)=g(w)$ for some pair $(w,g(w))$.

Complexity is $O(n^2)$.

**Application to "numbers" and arithmetic progression**

We consider the initial problem of detecting arithmetic progressions
in the elements of a list.

The three lists of the abstract case are the same list. The function $f$
is addition, and the function $g$ is doubling (i.e. product by 2).

The ordered set solution applies well to integers, rationals, or reals (with
some care).

Complex numbers are not an [ordered field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field). However they can be considered as an ordered groups with respect to addition, by prioritizing coordinates, so that $a+ib> a'+ib'$ iff $a>a' \vee (a=a' \wedge b>b')$. So the ordered set construction can be used.

The hash table algorithm seems necessary in the case of
$\mathbb{Z}/p$ (i.e. integers modulo $P$) since non-trivial [linearly ordered groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group) are
necessarily infinite, which is not the case for $\mathbb{Z}/p$.

However the ordered set construction could be adapted to
$\mathbb{Z}/p$ without loss in complexity, by allowing the list $L$
to be scanned twice, with some proper bookkeeping.

Comment: I don't understand why your `General Solution` is O(n^2). The checking in hashtable is O(n), this should be O(n^3). The solution for `case of ordered sets` is very well explained.

Comment: @randomA You are correct in the sense that my answer was not precise
enough. This is true only under the [Simple Uniform Hashing Assumption
(SHUA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_%28computer_science%29). Though
often used, this is not a totally inoccuous assumption, and I should
have been more careful. This a bit glossed over in a [text on hash
tables](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec20.html)
I had just looked at. I will amend the answer accordingly, as soon as
I finish some minor changes I was preparing. Thanks. - - - - I did not much like the H-table anyway.

Comment: @randomA Actually, I think it is not the hash table check in constant-time that you
should criticize, as much as my assertion that the hash table building
is in linear time. If the checking is not in constant time, then
building the table cannot be linear.

Comment: you are right, that one as well

Comment: @randomA Modified. Is it clear?

Comment: Good to see an answer improve due to feedback! Please remember to clean up the comments afterwards, either by deleting or flagging (including this). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An often-useful technique is to sort the list first. Then, starting with the smallest element, $x_1$, consider pairing $x_1$ with $x_2$. For them to be the first two terms in an arithmetic sequence, you'll need to have an $x_i = (x_2-x_1)+x_2$. You can find such an element by, say, a binary search. If that fails, look at the pair $x_1, x_3$ and do the same thing. Once you've exhausted the pairs starting at $x_1$, look at the pairs $x_2, x_3$, then $x_2, x_4$ and continue, counting the successes.

The sorting will take $O(n\log n)$ steps. You'll have to check $O(n^2)$ pairs and for each do a binary search for the third element, for a total of $O(n\log n+n^2\log n)$ steps.

There are some improvements you can make to this algorithm, but this should get you started.

Comment: Avoid the binary search. Sort the list. For each fixed $x_1=a$ let $x_3=c$ run over the list, and check whether $x_1=x_3$ equals $2x_2=2b$ for some element $x_2$ in the list by moving $x_2$ over the list together with $x_2$. $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @HendrikJan - no need to move the $x_2$. We can create a hash table from the original list and verify that $(x_1 + x_3) / 2$ is in the table in $O(1)$ time

Comment: I do not see that using a hash table will improve the complexity, but
it might hurt the efficiency (more complex code). However, for numbers
that cannot be sorted, you can apply @HendrikJan 's method to the list
in any order, and have the list of doubles $2b$ in a hash table for
checking. This can be abstracted to apply to lots of data with
whatever weird operator you wish to use.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list increasingly, in time $O(n\log(n))$.

For every $j$, consider the two sequences formed by the left-differences $L[j]-L[j-1], L[j]-L[j-2],L[j]-L[j-3]...$ and the right-differences $L[j+1]-L[j],L[j+2]-L[j],L[j+3]-L[j]...$

By a simple list merging process, you will detect all equal values in the two lists, corresponding to arithmetic triples, using no more than $\min(j,n-j)$ comparisons.

Repeating for all $j$, you count all arithmetic triples in time $\Theta(n^2)$.

```
# Input (presorted)
L= [ 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11 ]; n= len(L)

# Try all middle elements
for j in range(1, n - 1):
    # Detect all arithmetic triples by merging the left and right lists
    i= j - 1; k= j + 1
    while 0 <= i and k < n:
        if L[j] - L[i] < L[k] - L[j]:
            # Advance in the left list
            i-= 1
        elif L[j] - L[i] > L[k] - L[j]:
            # Advance in the right list
            k+= 1
        else:
            # Report a triple and advance in both lists
            print L[i], L[j], L[k]; i-= 1; k+= 1
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
3 6 9
1 6 11
3 7 11
7 9 11
```

This is worst-case optimal, as a perfect arithmetic sequence has $\Omega(n^2)$ arithmetic triples. Constant extra space.

A much harder challenge is to find an output-sensitive solution (when the number of arithmetic triples is $o(n^2)$).

Comment: Before you learn it the hard way: after 10 edits, your contribution automatically becomes community wiki. And you no longer get rep for the upvotes. So avoid minor edits, or save them for later.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Usually I can't help it: proofreading and proofreading again.

Comment: I know, I work that way too. But SE loves small bugs and approximative grammar.

Comment: It definitely does not! We like *well-prepared* posts, but we also like improvements, of course. This has been discussed/explained on [meta] before ([1](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/754/98), [2](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/669/98)). However, many (insignificant) edits are troublesome because it keeps bumping the thread. Find some recommendations on preparing posts [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/729/98). (cc @babou) Good to have another user on board who cares about quality!

Comment: @Raphael I was waiting for your reply. And you know I do not buy all of it. So I live with the situation best I can. But I would have cleaner posts if I could do small edits. As it is I preserve my edit count for real technical issues, like the feed-back above. I try to do small edits at the same time, but I do not always remember what they are.

Comment: @babou Well, I agree that preventing small polishing is not ideal, but *given* how the platform works it can't be helped. There are many discussions on [meta.SE] on this, including proposals to just not bump minor edits to the main page, but no one knows how to reliably detect such edits. So, as you say, we'll have to live with the limitations reality puts on our ideals.

Comment: @Raphael Another point, that should not surprise you. It happened several times to me that I carefully prepared an answer, taking time to polish it, only to discover that it had been put on hold in the mean time. I have seen excellent questions being put on hold by high rep experts, who did not understand the topic, for lack of knowledge, not to mention improper remarks (but I too am occasionally guilty of the latter).

Comment: @babou That is to be expected. The proper response is to improve the question (which I'd assume would be necessary), comment, vote for reopening and maybe take it to [meta]. Anyway, if you want to continue discussing these things, please do so in [chat]; this is not the right place.